# Creating Html Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some issues creating a string of html in javascript. It puts the quotes in the wrong spot and it frankly doesnt look like a very elegant way of doing it. Is there a cleaner way of creating the html below? Can someone shoot am an example of this?

```
 $(filterList).append('<li id=\'' + filterItemId  + '\'data-icon=\'delete\'><a onclick=' + '\'removeFilterItem(\'' + filterItemId + '\'' + ')\'>' + name + '</a></li>').listview('refresh');
```

I am trying to make an html string (created by the variables above) that looks like..

```
<li id="someId" data-icon="delete"><a onclick="removeFilterItem('someId')">Jack</a></li>
```

Comment: You should use double-quotes to ease the pain.

Comment: In JavaScript you can use either single or double quotes, what I do in cases like this is use the single quotes for the outside of my string, and double quotes inside. If you have more (and more complex) html that you need to render you might want to consider using some sort of js templating solution,

Comment: You can use double quotes " too so you won't have to escape single quotes '

Comment: Ive spent 2 hours trying to get the quotes right. I must be missing something?

Comment: `$(filterList).append('<li id="' + + filterItemId  + '" data-icon="delete"><a onclick="removeFilterItem(' + filterItemId + ')">' + name + '</a></li>').listview('refresh');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double quotes interchangeably with single quotes to avoid having to escape single quotation marks inside themselves.

```
$(filterList).append('<li id="' + filterItemId  + '"data-icon="delete"><a onclick="removeFilterItem(\'' + filterItemId + '\')">' + name + '</a></li>').listview('refresh');
```

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with using both types of quotes to build up your string:

```
$(filterList).append("<li id='" + filterItemId  + "' data-icon='delete'><a onclick='removeFilterItem('" + filterItemId + "' \>" + name + "</a></li>").listview('refresh');
```

Comment: In one or two places I could see this working wonderfully, but across the whole program? Someone is going to miss the quote double quote double quote quote. Just unconscionable.

Comment: You should look at jQuery templating if you have a lot of content to work with. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-an-introduction-to-jquery-templating/

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you can use either single or double quotes, what I usually do in cases like this is use the single quotes for the outside of my string, and double quotes inside. If you find that you need to do this often, and espeically if the html is more complex you might want to consider using some sort of js templating solution.

For your example the following should work

```
$(filterList).append('<li id="' + + filterItemId  + '" data-icon="delete"><a onclick="removeFilterItem(' + filterItemId + ')">' + name + '</a></li>').listview('refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to set your properties instead of trying to write a string.  This wya you don't have to worry about string escaping.

```
var $li = $("<li>");
var $a = $("<a>");

$a.appendTo($li);

$li.attr("id", someID);

$a.attr("onclick", "...");

// ...
$(filterList).append($li);
```

and so on.

Comment: I would `+1` this if you used the clearer syntax: `$("<li>", {id:someID})` and `$("<a>",{click: func...})`

Comment: I'm not familiar with that jquery syntax.  Nice addition. +1 to you

Answer (score 0):

You may use double quotes and precompute some strings :

```
 var script = "removeFilterItem('" + filterItemId + "');"
 $(filterList).append(
    '<li id="' + filterItemId + '" data-icon="delete">'
    + '<a onclick="'+script+'">' + name + '</a>'
    + '</li>'
 ).listview('refresh');
```

Note also that indentation and breaking down also ease the task (and the maintaining).

Answer (score 0):

```
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.id = "someId";
li.setAttribute("data-icon", "delete");
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.onclick = function() { removeFilterItem('someId'); };
li.appendChild(a);
```

I don't think there is very much to explain.